# Streaming bytes to network websocket

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have a code that uses a file handle to simulate sink for the streaming `Bytestring` from a source (`AWS S3`). If we want to use [`Network.Websocket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.9.6.2/docs/Network-WebSockets.html) as the sink, would it suffice to swap `LBS.writeFile` in the code below with [`sendBinaryData`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.9.6.2/docs/Network-WebSockets.html#g:4) (with handle to connection)?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings,ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Aws
import qualified Aws.S3 as S3
import           Data.Conduit (($$+-))
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL (mapM_)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.HTTP as SP
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import Streaming as S
import Streaming.Prelude as S hiding (show,print)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (async,waitCatch)
import Data.Text as T (Text)

data AwsConfig a = AwsConfig { _aws_cfg :: Aws.Configuration, _aws_s3cfg :: S3.S3Configuration a, _aws_httpmgr :: SP.Manager }

getObject :: AwsConfig Aws.NormalQuery -> T.Text -> T.Text ->  IO Int
getObject cfg bucket key = do
  req <- waitCatch =<< async (runResourceT $ do
    {- Create a request object with S3.getObject and run the request with pureAws. -}
    S3.GetObjectResponse { S3.gorResponse = rsp, S3.gorMetadata = mdata } <- 
      Aws.pureAws (_aws_cfg cfg) (_aws_s3cfg cfg) (_aws_httpmgr cfg) $
        S3.getObject bucket key
    {- Stream the response to a lazy bytestring -}
    liftIO $ LBS.writeFile "testaws" LBS.empty -- this will be replaced by content-length of the bytes 
    let obj = (($$+- CL.mapM_ S.yield) . hoist lift ) (SP.responseBody rsp)
    S.mapM_ (liftIO . (LBS.appendFile "testaws") . LBS.fromStrict) obj
    return $ lookup "content-length" (S3.omUserMetadata mdata))
  case req of
    Left _ -> return 2 -- perhaps, we could use this to send an error message over websocket
    Right _ -> return 0
```

The source of confusion for me is how the termination of the stream is determined? In case of files, this is taken care of by `writeFile` API. What about `sendBinaryData`? Does it handle termination in similar way as `writeFile`? Or is it determined by the data parser on the client side?

**Update**

This question is about how to stream the data to a websocket handle (let us assume a handle has been provided) like we do with the file handle in the example above, not really about how to manage the handle within `resourceT`. `conduit` does seem to take [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-websockets-0.2.4/docs/src/Yesod-WebSockets.html#sinkWSBinary) approach to sink data. So, it seems that is indeed the way to go.

The *termination* question is because of this line of thought I have: if we have a function listening for data on the other side of a Websocket handle, then determining end of message seems to matter in streaming context. Given a function like below:

```
f :: LBS.ByteString -> a
```

if we do `S.mapM_` to stream the data to websocket handle, does it take care of adding some kind of `end of stream` marker so that `f` listening on the other side can stop processing the lazy bytestring. Otherwise `f` won't know when the message is complete.

Comment: Why are you using Lazy ByteString at all in this program?

Comment: @Michael, perhaps ignorance at my part. Can swap with strict bytestring.

Comment: It think I see now, it's coming from `websockets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few bits and pieces that may make things more intelligible. First, for the first little demo, revising your `getObject`, I use `Streaming.ByteString.writeFile`, which is in `ResourceT` anyway, to drop the detour by lazy bytestring.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings,ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Aws
import qualified Aws.S3 as S3
import           Data.Conduit 
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL (mapM_)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.HTTP as HTTP
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming as SB
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.Internal as SB
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import           Streaming as S
import           Streaming.Prelude as S hiding (show,print)
import           Control.Concurrent.Async (async,waitCatch)
import           Data.Text as T (Text) 
import qualified Network.WebSockets as WebSockets
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource

data AwsConfig a = AwsConfig { _aws_cfg :: Aws.Configuration
                             , _aws_s3cfg :: S3.S3Configuration a
                             , _aws_httpmgr :: HTTP.Manager }

getObject :: AwsConfig Aws.NormalQuery -> FilePath -> T.Text -> T.Text ->  IO Int
getObject cfg file bucket key = do
  req <- waitCatch =<< async (runResourceT $ do
    S3.GetObjectResponse { S3.gorResponse = rsp, S3.gorMetadata = mdata } <- 
      Aws.pureAws (_aws_cfg cfg) (_aws_s3cfg cfg) (_aws_httpmgr cfg) $
        S3.getObject bucket key
    let bytestream = do 
         -- lookup "content-length" (S3.omUserMetadata mdata))
         SB.chunk B.empty -- this will be replaced by content-length 
         hoist lift (HTTP.responseBody rsp)  $$+- CL.mapM_ SB.chunk 
    SB.writeFile file bytestream ) -- this is in ResourceT 
  case req of
    Left _ -> return 2
    Right _ -> return 0
```

We can abstract from this more or less what you were doing with `SB.writeFile`:

```
getObjectAbstracted
      :: (SB.ByteString (ResourceT IO) () -> ResourceT IO b)
         -> AwsConfig Aws.NormalQuery -> S3.Bucket -> Text -> ResourceT IO b
getObjectAbstracted action cfg bucket key = do
    S3.GetObjectResponse { S3.gorResponse = rsp, S3.gorMetadata = mdata } <- 
      Aws.pureAws (_aws_cfg cfg) 
                  (_aws_s3cfg cfg) 
                  (_aws_httpmgr cfg) 
                  (S3.getObject bucket key)

    action (hoist lift (HTTP.responseBody rsp)  $$+- CL.mapM_ SB.chunk)
```

Here now, we need a little helper not included in the streaming bytestring library

```
mapMChunks_ :: Monad m => (B.ByteString -> m ()) -> SB.ByteString m r -> m r
mapMChunks_ act bytestream = do
  (a S.:> r) <- SB.foldlChunksM (\_ bs -> act bs) (return ()) bytestream
  return r
```

and can proceed more or less as @haoformayor planned, using streaming bytestring

```
writeConnection :: MonadIO m => WebSockets.Connection -> SB.ByteString m r -> m r
writeConnection connection  = 
  mapMChunks_ (liftIO . WebSockets.sendBinaryData connection)

-- following `haoformayor`
connectWrite
    :: (MonadResource m, WebSockets.WebSocketsData a) 
    => WebSockets.PendingConnection 
    -> a                  -- closing  message
    -> SB.ByteString m r  -- stream from aws
    -> m r
connectWrite request closeMessage bytestream = do
    (releaseKey, connection) <- allocate (WebSockets.acceptRequest request)
                                         (`WebSockets.sendClose` closeMessage)
    writeConnection connection bytestream

getObjectWS :: WebSockets.WebSocketsData a =>
       WebSockets.PendingConnection
       -> a
       -> AwsConfig Aws.NormalQuery
       -> S3.Bucket
       -> Text
       -> ResourceT IO ()
getObjectWS request closeMessage = getObjectAbstracted (connectWrite request closeMessage)
```

Of course none of this so far makes any use of the difference between `conduit` and `streaming`/`streaming-bytestring`.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in thinking that handles will require additional trickery. However, as you are already using the `ResourceT` monad transformer, this is [delightfully simple to do with `allocate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.7.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#g:5). `allocate` allows you to create a handle in the resource monad and register a cleanup action (which in your case is just closing the connection).

```
ok <- runResourceT $ do
  (releaseKey, handle) <-
    allocate (WebSockets.acceptRequest request) 
             (`WebSockets.sendClose` closeMessage)
  WebSockets.sendBinaryData handle data
  return ok
where
  request = ...
  closeMessage = ...
  data = ...
  ok = ...
```

By using `allocate`, the handle is guaranteed to close by the time `runResourceT` returns `ok`.

I am not entirely sure that this is what you want, however. It seems to me that `getObject` should not know about how to accept and close WS connections; perhaps it should take a WS connection handle as an argument and then write to it. If you upgrade its return type to `ResourceT` then you could charge the *caller* to `getObject` with the responsibility of calling  `runResourceT` and allocating WS handles and so forth. But hopefully the example above is enough to get you going on your way.

Comment: Yep, `getObject` doesn't need to accept and close WS connections. It is already taken care of somewhere else. We just pass `WS connection` handle to the function. However, to write to it, don't we need to do `mapM_` to send the data to Websocket handle? That was the original question - how to stream the data to WS handle like we do to the file. It is not really about handle management.

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat - code not tested.)

Your code is re-opening the output file and appending to it every time a packet of data comes in. Clearly a better solution is to use `LBS.hPutStr` to write to the file using an already open file handle.

That is, instead of:

```
S.mapM_ (liftIO . (LBS.appendFile "testaws") . LBS.fromStrict) obj
```

you want to use:

```
S.mapM_ (liftIO . (LBS.hPutStr h) . LBS.fromStrict) obj
```

Of course, this references the handle `h`, and where does that come from?

One solution is to pass it into `getObject` or otherwise create it before calling the body of `getObject`, e.g.:

```
getObject cfg bucket key = withFile "output" $ \h -> do
    req <- ...
    ...
    S.mapM_ (liftIO . (LBS.hPutStr h) . LBS.fromStrict) obj
    ...
```

Or maybe you have to creating inside the runResourceT... I'm not sure.

**Update** - See @haoformayor's answer for how to have ResourceT manage the file handle for you.